# upgrade procedure

Tags: baker, setup

when an election is in adoption phase how do we change our baking scripts?

do we run ALL of

```
./tezos-endorser-010-PtGRANAD
./tezos-baker-010-PtGRANAD
./tezos-accuser-010-PtGRANAD
-with- 
./tezos-endorser-011-PtHangz2
./tezos-baker-011-PtHangz2
./tezos-accuser-011-PtHangz2
```

concurrently? or do we choose the higher level only?

Comment: Yes, run 010 and 011 at the same time BEFORE the adoption phase finishes. Then AFTER 011 activates, you can stop all 010 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your baker to remain active at all times, you need to launch the Hangzhou daemons before the activation and to stop the Granada ones after the activation so for a period of time you will indeed run daemons for both versions concurrently. There is no particular risk in doing that, they cannot interfere and the extra resources are low.